# Objective C: How to implement undo button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I am using Core Graphics for my Paint App school project and i want it to have an undo button
but i don't know how, it's my first time to get this close to Objective C, any help?

i already have the button connected to its outlet and sent event, the code now is my problem.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Core Data to store each paint event. [Undo Management is a built-in feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245785/undo-management-with-core-data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read up on [NSUndoManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score -3):

I didn't clear your question ,my assumption is when you pain with some colors in the view,you have to undo right?so you want to code cancel the last touch event of the view.The basic idea is cancel last touch.You can code it in tozuchevent delegates and call by that cede in button.

Comment: yes! that's the idea, canceling the last touch but with the use of a UIButton.